# How to QUERY a value from each row based on another column result?

Tags: sql, hive, hql

So i have a DB that have an unique ID for each client and everyday this DB updates the "proposal" of said client.

My issue is that i need to grab the ID, result and date of the latest Approved proposal otherwise the latest reproval of said client if he has no approved proposals inside a given time interval(the time interval is not a issue for me)
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7efNd.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe8EZ.png)

I use ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) to fetch always the latest proposal but with the conditional that i explained i cant make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step:

- create a rank based on both results i.e approved and re-approved based on the id and the result values.
- Filter on `rank_ = 1`, this would fetch recent values for both result values if exist
- Create a count to check if one id has more than 1 row after fetching the latest date per id for both result values
- create a boolean to filter out the non-relevant rows

```
with main as (
select 
*, row_number (over partition by id, result order by date desc) as rank_
from table
),
totals as (
select *, count(*) over(partition by id) as total_results
 from main where rank_ = 1
),
conditions as (
select 
case 
when total_results = 1 then true
when total_results > 1 and lower(result) = 'approved' then true
else false end as is_relevant_row
from totals
)
select * from conditions where is_relevant_row
```